# MySQL/MariaDB drop user with long user name fails

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm running MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.9-MariaDB for OSX10.13 and have a bunch of users (around 14) where the username is apparently too long, see below.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+-------------------------+
| Host      | User                    |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_2SxSBywyXh3QW5L4 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_4j3CWVXjgtDD2OrI |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_6C3vAqBTVns8rMTT |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_9PVCY1Msa61u43Oh |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_RyFspluIGEi3Fkby |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_SQtfEQZmWRFfKmHy |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_VC8pYaJ3it1LdYK3 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_Zr84h3vkLdwkqR33 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_cvifD1I2Rjghjnpu |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_jO1tUJJokremTW5P |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_p6Bhzhi0OqMH4gc9 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_rjyOX1NqEN6k6mk4 |
| 127.0.0.1 | tenant_xfcHjsn0mHBfURAw |
| 127.0.0.1 | test_testing_local      |
| localhost | mysql.session           |
| localhost | mysql.sys               |
| localhost | root                    |
+-----------+-------------------------+
18 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

When I try to drop these users using the following command I'm in encountering this error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@127.0.0.1';
ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@127.0.0.1' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 32)
MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@localhost';
ERROR 1470 (HY000): String 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@localhost' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 32)
```

Any idea's on how I can drop these users?

Most annoying side effect of this is when opening up SequalPro, and I get 14 errors (one after the other) notifying me of this user name being too long issue.

[image]

Also, another odd question that I'd be interested to hear about is why when these user name are only 22-24 characters long are they causing a **... too long for user name (should be no longer than 32)** error, as they don't breach the 32 character limit?

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try several options. Can try the latest test build of SequelPro. The test build (3477d22) seems to solve the long names issue for me.
Test Builds are here: https://sequelpro.com/test-builds

Or one of the latest development builds. http://nightly.sequelpro.com/
For me, with Mariadb 10.x server and nightly build, it also worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Downloading the latest test build worked. It allowed me to delete those users without the string on validation errors :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to comment the 'username' @ 'host' ...

Use:

```
DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: That just produces this erro: `MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2I'@'127.0.0.1';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2'@'127.0.0.1'`

Comment: @JasonMortonNZ - Does that username end in `I2I`?  Or just `I2`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.3.11-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> DESC mysql.user; -- User char(80)
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                              | Null | Key | Default  | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
| Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |          |       |
| User                   | char(80)                          | NO   | PRI |          |       |
.
.
.
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+-------+
47 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2'@'127.0.0.1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@127.0.0.1';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2@127.0.0.1'@'%'

MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2I'@'127.0.0.1'; -- Wrong user
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2I'@'127.0.0.1'

MariaDB [(none)]> DROP USER 'tenant_5OOBxRgjSvFehwI2'@'127.0.0.1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
```